# Is there an easy way to deploy a Rails 3.1 assets bundle to RackSpace CloudFiles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rackspace

I recently built out a CDN using Amazons' S3 service and CloudFront.  It is super easy to setup with the new assets management in rails 3.1.

However, my other project has an established hosting on Rackspace.  I use the Rackspace Cloudfiles for image storage, much like Amazon S3 storage works.  However, I cannot find an easy way to setup the Rackspace CloudFiles to load my asset package and host it.

Any tips or processes for doing this would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at https://github.com/rumblelabs/asset_sync, I'm using it on Rackspace Files

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try.  It looks good.  I ended up setting up an AWS account since they are so easy to use.  It's only costing me about $.10 / month, so not even worth the trouble of doing something else yet.

Comment: With AWS there is an option to use an "Origin", with that you just tell cloud_files where your source is and when it gets a request for something it checks there.  It takes about 5 min to setup and just works.  So you really don't need something as complex as asset_sync if you are using AWS.